# XCode 7: Linker linking to an SDK that doesn't show up in Build Settings

Tags: ios, facebook, sdk, linker, xcode7

I spent about an hour removing the Facebook SDK from the codebase I'm working on for an iOS app. I know that within my code there are no more references to Facebook.

I get the following error:

```
(null): Directory not found for option '-F/Users/admin/Documents/FacebookSDK'
```

I looked at my Build Settings/Search Paths and in both there is no reference to the Facebook SDK in my Project Explorer at all.

[Build settings image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/muMMy.png)

I'm fairly certain this is causing my following error:

```
Symbol(s) not found for architecture i386 
(preceded by 9 counts of various Facebook class references)
```

I have searched for similar issues but can't see any other references to this kind of problem. Any clue as to why the Linker would be trying to link an SDK that doesn't otherwise show up?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check your build target. From the 'Architecture i386' bit it looks like you have a Active Scheme of 'My Mac 64 bit' or something along those lines. You should be building for iPhone.

I am still using XCode 5.x and I do not know how to check it in XCode 7.x. With XCode 5.x, the scheme is displayed near the top of the window.

If the Active Scheme is iPhone, then check your scheme settings for the active scheme.

If the Scheme is right, then check your build target. Make sure your build target is for iPhone.

Comment: My active scheme is definitely iPhone 6. Build target is my app executable. iOS7 as the iOS deployment target in build settings. No clue what's going on.

I also tried editing the scheme to build without implicit dependencies unsure if that'd change anything but it didn't appear to have an effect.

What's even more frustrating is that if I roll back to a previous commit on git (before another dev stupidly reincorporated all the facebook trash with his code) it builds and compiles fine.

Comment: Check your build log. Make sure you've removed the offending library(ies) from the project as well as the build target(s). Make sure you have removed it from the Frameworks section of the left hand pane. Check the build phases for the target(s) to make sure the library is not listed.

Comment: Ok so first thing I noticed was this: 
    

`/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/clang -arch i386 -isysroot`

 But after that I noticed


    `-F/Users/admin/Documents/FacebookSDK`


 in the path. There is no FacebookSDK asset in my file structure. I can't tell where it's coming from.

Comment: Oh and there's no reference to the Facebook SDK in the phases.

Comment: Ok got it. I thought there were no references but it was clipping the last item in the build. I got that.

Didn't solve my errors though but that's separate to the issue I now know.

Thanks so much for all the help.